# Keras LSTM None value output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

this is my data `X_train` prepared for LSTM of shape (7000, 2, 200)

```
[[[0.500858   0.         0.5074856  ... 1.         0.4911533  0.        ]
  [0.4897923  0.         0.48860878 ... 0.         0.49446714 1.        ]]

 [[0.52411383 0.         0.52482396 ... 0.         0.48860878 1.        ]
  [0.4899698  0.         0.48819458 ... 1.         0.4968341  1.        ]]

 ...

 [[0.6124623  1.         0.6118705  ... 1.         0.6328777  0.        ]
  [0.6320492  0.         0.63512635 ... 1.         0.6960175  0.        ]]

 [[0.6118113  1.         0.6126989  ... 0.         0.63512635 1.        ]
  [0.63530385 1.         0.63595474 ... 1.         0.69808865 0.        ]]]
```

I create my sequential model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 200)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
```

Then I fit my model:

```
history = model.fit(
    X_train, 
    Y_train, 
    epochs = 20, 
    batch_size = 200, 
    validation_data = (X_test, Y_test), 
    verbose = 1, 
    shuffle = False,
)
model.summary()
```

And at the end I can see something like this:

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_16 (LSTM)              (None, 2, 50)             50200     
                                                                 
 dropout_10 (Dropout)        (None, 2, 50)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_10 (Dense)            (None, 2, 1)              51
```

Why does it say that output shape have a `None` value as a first element? Is it a problem? Or it should be like this? What does it change and how can I change it?

I will appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value in TensorFlow is always reserved for the `batch-size`. Your model doesn't know in advance what is your `batch-size` so it makes it None. If we go into more details let's suppose your dataset is **1000 samples** and your **`batch-size`** is 32. So, **1000/32** will become **31.25**, if we just take the floor value which is **31**. So, there would be 31 batches in a total of size 32. But if you look here the total sample size of your dataset is **1000** but you have **31 batches** of size **32**, which is **32 * 31 = 992**, where **1000 - 992 = 8**, it means there would be one more batch of size **8**. But the model doesn't know in advance so, what does it do? it reserves a space in the memory where it doesn't define a specific shape for it, in other words, the memory is dynamic for the **`batch-size`**. Therefore, you are seeing it **None** there. So, the model doesn't know in advance what would be the shape of my **batch-size** so it makes it **None** so it should know it later when it computes the **first epoch** meaning computes all of the **batches**.

The **None** value can't be changed because it is **Dynamic** in Tensorflow, the model knows it and fix it when your model completes its **first epoch**. So, always set the shapes which are after it like in your case it is **`(2, 200)`**. **The 7000** is your model's total number of samples so the model doesn't know in advance what would be your **batch-size** and the other big issue is most of the time your **batch-size** is not evenly divisible by your **total number of samples in dataset** therefore, it is necessary for the model to make it **None** to know it later when it computes all the batches in the very first epoch.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect so detailed and well written explaination, thank you!